# Bootstrap Wizard cant get rid of tooltip disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Im creating a Bootstrap wizard for users to go through. For the life of me I cant get the "Next" button on the last tab to work. It has a disabled tooltip picture over it.

[image]

**What I have tried:**

1. I searched in the Stack and found a suggestion to remove the "disabled" class from the "next" button but the class isn't there in the first place.
2. I checked to see if there is a validation rule but none exist on the last tab.

Comment: Now you have 10 reputation, please attach your picture. However, a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be much better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
I hid the Next button on the last tab and unhid a Finish button. This way Bootstrap was not able to disable the button. Not ideal solution but the only one I could think of since there was nothing in the documentation or forums.